# How to compute this multivariable limit with a sine?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Here is the multivariable limit that I’m trying to compute:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y),$$

where $f(x,y)=\dfrac{x(sin(y))^2}{x^2+y^4}$. I’m pretty sure this limit exists but I’m not sure how to compute it. I tried using the squeeze theorem but do not know which functions I should compare this to. Do people have any thoughts or ideas on how to do it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi PC1, can you use l’hopital for two variable functions? I thought you can’t.

Comment: @PC1 the function has more than 1 variable

Comment: @PC1 This argument is not true, L'Hopital Rule is exclusive for function of one variable. Indeed, the limit does not exists.

Comment: Yes deleted my comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit does not exists!

Along the curve $x=y^2$ the limit is equal to $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Along the curve $x=0$ it is obvious $0$.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer. May I ask how you simplify it to 1/2? I got x(sinsqrt(x))^2/(2x^2). Is it possible to simplify this to 1/2?

Comment: @TobiasLo along the curve $x=y^2$ the limit simplifies to $\dfrac{\sin^2y}{2y^2}$, from here just applies the fundamental limit.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!